# Difference between blocks from filefrag and stat

Tags: linux, files, size, stat

I have created file named `sometext` with random data inside. I wanted to check metadata of this file using several programs. I have used `filefrag` and `stat` program.

```
 kd@kd-VPCEB2S1E ~/Downloads $ stat sometext 
  File: 'sometext'
  Size: 16          Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 801h/2049d  Inode: 6298184     Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1000/  kd)   Gid: ( 1000/  kd)
Access: 2018-04-19 09:39:07.263246674 +0200
Modify: 2018-04-19 09:39:06.527234524 +0200
Change: 2018-04-19 09:39:06.527234524 +0200
 Birth: -
kd@kd-VPCEB2S1E ~/Downloads $ filefrag -v sometext 
Filesystem type is: ef53
File size of sometext is 16 (1 block of 4096 bytes)
 ext:     logical_offset:        physical_offset: length:   expected: flags:
   0:        0..       0:   25369307..  25369307:      1:             last,eof
sometext: 1 extent found
kd@kd-VPCEB2S1E ~/Downloads $
```

Both programs shows that the file size is `16 bytes`  and the `block` size is `4096 bytes`. So far so good, but `stat` show that file takes `8 blocks` and `filefrag` show that file takes `1 block`.

Why there is such big difference? What have I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**IO block** is *chunk size* for interchange with block device.

**Block** (`stat`) is number of filesystem *cells* (and of cause depend on filesystem type), needed for store a file. It's can be easy to test:

```
$ stat shell
  File: ‘shell’
  Size: 4295        Blocks: 16         IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fd00h/64768d    Inode: 16997503    Links: 1
Access: (0755/-rwxr-xr-x)  Uid: ( 1000/   yurij)   Gid: ( 1000/   yurij)
Access: 2018-04-11 18:17:38.614827347 +0300
Modify: 2018-04-11 18:17:34.359967012 +0300
Change: 2018-04-19 01:07:03.729000000 +0300
 Birth: - 

$ pwd
/home/yurij/develop/shell/usr/local/bin
$ sudo blockdev --getbsz /dev/mapper/cl-root
[sudo] password for yurij:
512 # cell size in bytes
```

8 KB = 8192 bytes

8192 bytes / 512 bytes = 16 Blocks

`filefrag`:

```
$ filefrag -v shell
Filesystem type is: 58465342
File size of shell is 4295 (2 blocks of 4096 bytes)
 ext:     logical_offset:        physical_offset: length:   expected: flags:
   0:        0..       1:    1141480..   1141481:      2:             eof
shell: 1 extent found
```

It's two read/write operations need to read/write file from/to block device.